# `gc()` destroys an object that I still have a reference to in QML

Tags: qt, qml

In C++ code I have in invokable function that creates a table model:

```
class ExchangeModel : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    ExchangeModel(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    Q_INVOKABLE QObject * getMarkets() { return new MyTableModel(); }
    
    ...
};
```

where `MyTableModel` is a class derived from `QAbstractListModel`.

In my QML code I have a `TableView`

```
TableView
{
    id: ml
    ...
}
```

and a working function that assigns `TableView`s model to my model:

```
function openList()
{
    var list = exchangeModel.getMarkets()
    ml.model = list
}
```

But, if I transform my `openList()` function into this:

```
function doOpenList()
{
    var list = exchangeModel.getMarkets()
    ml.model = list
}

function openList()
{
    doOpenList()
    //gc() requires the control to leave the scope to delete the model.
    gc()
}
```

my application starts to crash, because `gc()` call destroys my model (`list` variable), despite the fact that I assign it to `ml.model` and my `TableView` still exists.

However, the following function does not crash:

```
function openList()
{
    var list = exchangeModel.getMarkets()
    ml.model = list
    gc()
}
```

and **not always** immediately delete the previous model, but deletion **can be** delayed until the function is called next time.

And `delete` does not help

```
function openList()
{
    var list = exchangeModel.getMarkets()
    var old_model = ml.model
    ml.model = list
    delete old_model
    gc()
}
```

I need the old model to be deleted immediately after the new model is assigned, but `gc()` either delete what I do not want it to delete or does not delete what I want it to delete.

**EDIT1:**

Actually there is no difference between

```
function openList()
{
    var list = exchangeModel.getMarkets(sortBy)
    ml.model = list
}
```

and

```
function openList()
{
    var list = exchangeModel.getMarkets(sortBy)
    ml.model = list
    gc()
}
```

and it is also not clear why. With the both above implementations the old model randomly either deleted immediately or deleted the next time `openList()` is called.

But note that this:

```
function doOpenList()
{
    var list = exchangeModel.getMarkets(sortBy)
    ml.model = list
}

function openList()
{
    doOpenList()
    //gc() requires the control to leave the scope to delete the model.
    gc()
}
```

results in a crash, as I mentioned before. So, finally, `gc()` either results in a crash or does not take an effect at all.

Comment: what happens if you don't call to gc? will the object be deleted too? what a reason to run garbage collection here? I mean wouldn't it be better to entrust this operation to the JS engine?

Comment: @folibis see EDIT1. Theoretically there can be multiple `TableView`s in my app with different table models and I want QML to control their lifetime. For example, I want the model to be destroyed when the user closes some page. And I need the model to be destroyed immediately, because it unsubscribes from some notification in its destructor (at C++ side) and stops some processing that consumes CPU.